# Why do I get I/O error 32 even though the file isn't open in any other program?

Tags: delphi, text-files, ioerror

I'm trying to write a line to a text file in Delphi 7 with the code below, but it gave this error:

"Raised Exception Class EInOutError with 'I/O error 32'"

```
AssignFile(trackertxt, 'tracker.txt');
ReWrite(trackertxt);
WriteLn(trackertxt, 'left'+':'+':');
CloseFile(trackertxt);
```

It's not being used by any other application, yet it still gives error 32.

(Also need it to overwrite the current content in the text file).

Comment: You need to clarify what you're trying. Just saying `Write()` or `WriteLn()` does not tell us what you're really trying to do. Please include all relevant code. But error code 32 tells me the file you're trying to write to is already open in another process.

Comment: The question is quite simple. I just want to know how to write 1 line of text to a .txt file.

Comment: Which is explained many, many times over on many, many different websites.

Comment: All the websites I've seen say to use WriteLn, which doesn't work for me. I wouldn't ask a question if I hadn't already tried to find the answer somewhere else.

Comment: Error code 32 means: "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."

Comment: Well, WriteLn does work. It does what it is supposed to do. You did not supply any code, or truly explain what you are trying to do. What does overwrite current line really mean?

Comment: It means overwrite the current line of text that is in the txt file. I closed all programs that were using the txt file but now it gave error 105.

Comment: Sorry, it actually still gives error code 32.

Comment: Text files don't have a "current line". Your questions makes no real sense. If you want to insert/overwrite text in the middle of a file, you probably cannot. Only possible if you are writing the same number of chars as was there before.

Comment: Updated question with the current code I am using.

Comment: Well, clearly something else has locked the file. Quite likely it's the same process that this code lives in. It's easy for you to see that the code in the question works fine. Just put that code in an empty program and observe that it works. Ergo, the problem is in the code you did not show. Always always provide a complete program the illustrates the problem. If you had tried to do that you'd have solved the problem yourself.

Comment: @David that reminds me of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13736707/modifying-or-deleting-a-line-from-a-text-file-the-low-level-way

Comment: How did you confirm that no other app is using it? Did you use some tools such as Process Monitor? And how about trying to write to another brand new text file?

Comment: Really? I post a link to a related question and it gets down-voted?

Answer (score 4):

this is a simple example on how to write a simple text file

source of example is - http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=TextFile

code:

```
var
  myFile : TextFile;
  text   : string;

begin
  // Try to open the Test.txt file for writing to
  AssignFile(myFile, 'Test.txt');
  ReWrite(myFile);

  // Write a couple of well known words to this file
  WriteLn(myFile, 'Hello World');

  // Close the file
  CloseFile(myFile);

  // Reopen the file for reading
  Reset(myFile);

  // Display the file contents
  while not Eof(myFile) do
  begin
    ReadLn(myFile, text);
    ShowMessage(text);
  end;

  // Close the file for the last time
  CloseFile(myFile);
end;
```

if the file is locked by another process, or already locked by the current process(as Remy Lebeau pointed out) then you get an error as described here http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/SysUtils_EInOutError.html

> 32  Sharing violation

that means that another process is using that file, and you can not save your changes until that process is done using the same file.

the following code taken from this website http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/torry/showcode.php?id=104 shows you how to verify if a file is already in use:

```
function IsFileInUse(FileName: TFileName): Boolean;
var
  HFileRes: HFILE;
begin
  Result := False;
  if not FileExists(FileName) then Exit;
  HFileRes := CreateFile(PChar(FileName),
                         GENERIC_READ or GENERIC_WRITE,
                         0,
                         nil,
                         OPEN_EXISTING,
                         FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                         0);
  Result := (HFileRes = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);
  if not Result then
    CloseHandle(HFileRes);
end;


procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if IsFileInUse('c:\Programs\delphi6\bin\delphi32.exe') then //here you need to change this with the path to the file you want to edit/write/etc
    ShowMessage('File is in use.');
  else
    ShowMessage('File not in use.');
end;
```

Comment: FYI, a sharing violation can also occur within the same process if it opens the file multiple times with conflicting access bits without closing the file in between each open.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - Correct. I will modify the answer to include this too.

Answer (score 2):

The code in your question will replace all content in the file with the text 'left::'. That part of your code is fine.

I/O error 32 is a sharing violation. The file is locked in a way that prevents your code writing to the file. Either another process, or even your own process has a lock on the file. The system doesn't lie. The file is already open somewhere which is why your code fails with error 32.

I think it most likely that your own program is the guilty party. Look at all the places in the code where you open that file. Do you have two or more file variables that are attached to that file? Are you 100% sure that you never open the file with one file variable whilst it is already open with another variable?