# How do i write to a specific point in a text file in delphi

Tags: delphi

I want to add a word to the text after a certain line, for example:
Here is the text in the text file:
5264564321323 ROO3 Rooney Will 234234 (i want to add something here)

this is the code i am currently trying to use:

```
var
  i: Integer;
  sl: TStringList;
begin
  sl := TStringList.Create;
  try
    sl.LoadFromFile('users.txt');
    for i := sl.Count-1 downto 0 do
      if Pos('R003', sl[i]) <> 0 then
        sl.Insert(i,'user'); //DOES NOT WORK, I DONT KNOW HOW TO IMPLEMENT IT

    sl.SaveToFile('users.txt');
  finally
    sl.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Not a duplicate, but related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13736707/modifying-or-deleting-a-line-from-a-text-file-the-low-level-way

Answer (score 5):

Your code is essentially fine. The problem is that the text you are searching for does not contain

```
R003
```

Instead it contains

```
ROO3
```

That is, you have used the number 0 instead of the letter O.

Note that your code inserts a new line in the file. If you intended to modify a line the you need to write

```
sl[i] := ...
```