# Delphi rewriting a single line

Tags: delphi, text-files

Can we rewrite a single line of a textfile and then save it and close it?

For example, i need to rewrite the first line, and keep all the others. Is there a function to do this or do i have to copy the whole file after changing a single line?

My file contains more than a thausand lines, and i only need to change the first line.

Example of file:

```
test;test1;test2
other;other;other
other;other;other
x1000
```

and then

```
something;something;something
other;other;other
other;other;other
x1000
```

See what i mean? I just want to keep my file like it is but change the first line. I could copy the whole file and paste it after i changed the first line but i wonder if there a method already included in delphi to only change a particular line in a text file. Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13736707/modifying-or-deleting-a-line-from-a-text-file-the-low-level-way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not possible. Files are stored linearly and do not support insertion. If your line was a fixed length, then you could overwrite it. However, you wish to replace the line with new content that is longer. That cannot be done. You'd need to re-write the entire file.

A database may be more appropriate for your needs than a text file.

Comment: Dump from a database? I hope you're not [doing this](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/A-Repetitive-Task.aspx)

Comment: +1 The question is clear and this is the only correct answer. As this is a Q&A site, the current accepted answer does **not** answer the question asked. OP should either alter the question, delete it or switch the accepted answer... *(getting grumpy in my old days... oh wel...)*

Comment: Not the points an sich *(David has enough of them)* but when accepting an answer you should pick the correct one for it to be usable for the next reader with the same question.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the easiest approach here would be using a TStringList in this way :

```
procedure InPlaceFileEdit(fFile : String);
begin
F:=TStringList.Create;
try
  F.LoadFromFile(fFile);
  F.Strings[0]:='something;something;something' ;// Change the contents of the first line
  F.SaveToFile(fFile);
finally
 F.Free
end
end;
```

Of course this is a trick that rewrite the file each time entirely.

Comment: Do note that this does exactly what you asked not to do, namely re-write the entire file. If the file needs to be changed in this way then you have no choice, but do not be mistaken in thinking that you are avoiding re-writing the file.

Comment: If you have a solution that rewrite only one line of a file you can post it here. Idk if delphi have that kind of 'editors' to work on a file

Comment: @user28470: Surely David wouldn't have posted an answer saying "This is not possible" if he knew of a way to solve your problem exactly as asked! It's fine that you've agreed to accept a solution you were trying to avoid initially. The problem as I see it is that you posted a question specifically asking to avoid a complete file rewrite and now you accept this answer, which does a complete file rewrite, with a comment "Works *perfectly*".

Comment: Cause i kinda expected it wouldn't be possible and as david sayed it's impossible i accepted this solution to please the person that toke her time to answer.

Comment: Note: this solution is not really an "in-place" editing. Entire file contents gets loaded into memory, parsed into individually addressable lines, edited, and then combined into overwritten original file.