# Delphi - Check each line of a file againt another file

Tags: delphi

I have to check each line of a file against another file.
If one line from the first file exists in the second file I have to delete it.
Right now i'm using 2 listboxes and the "for listbox1.items.count-1 downto do begin..."
My program works but I have to check this for huge files with over 1 milion lines.
Is there a faster approach to this method? 
I want to load the files inside memory in order to be extremely fast!
Thanks

Comment: *Is there a faster approach to this method?* Yes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modifying or deleting a line from a text file the low-level way?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13736707/modifying-or-deleting-a-line-from-a-text-file-the-low-level-way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use TStringList for this. List for second file should be sorted for faster search. Try this:

```
var
  l1, l2: TStringList;
  i: integer;
begin
  l1 := nil;
  l2 := nil;
  try
    l1 := TStringList.Create;
    l1.loadfromFile('file1');

    l2 := TStringList.Create;
    l2.LoadFromFile('file2');
    l2.Sorted := True;

    for i := l1.Count -1 downto 0 do
    begin
      if l2.IndexOf(l1[i]) <> -1 then
        l1.Delete(i);
    end;

    l1.SaveToFile('file1');
  finally
    FreeEndNil(l1);
    FreeEndNil(l2);
  end
end
```

Comment: This approach would use a LOT of memory for very large files.

Comment: Yes, I know, but this will be the fasterst solution I think. Also the memory not the problem for computers today.

Comment: You don't need the two lines at the beginning (that nil the two variables), and there's no need to use FreeAndNil to free them (they're local variables that will go out of scope at the end of the block).

Comment: This is going to be very expensive in terms of memory and CPU. Sorting followed by binary search costs.

Comment: @Evgeny: Actually, the memory issue is a BIG problem for large files. By the time `TStringList.LoadFromFile()` is ready to exit, it has allocated **3-4x the size of the source data** in memory buffers used for parsing (and that is not counting the memory used for the final substrings themselves). So, if you try to load a large file into a `TStringList`, you can easily run into out-of-memory errors, even on modern PCs and recent Delphi versions. I have reported this to Embarcadero before, but I can't find the report right now.

Comment: WOW! THIS IS SUPER FAST! Why is this method much faster than the listbox? I used almost the same logic but instead of Tstringslist i used listbox.However for 25573 lines of a file it took almost 9 minutes to complete using listbox.After deletion I also checked if the item was really deleted from listbox so I actually had to perform the operation twice.

Comment: @user2858981 Compare it with real life: What is faster? Simple compare two lists vs. painting two lists on a board and then compare both?

Comment: I suspected that but I wanted to have a confirmation from more experienced programmers. Thanks for the info. I'll keep that in mind next time i have to process 7 milion lines of strings. :) Listbox for show off , Stringlist for real work

Answer (score 1):

A quick solution (but not the fastest one) is to use two TStringList lists instead of list boxes.

```
var
  a, b: TStringList;
  i: Integer;
begin
  a := TStringList.Create;
  b := TStringList.Create;
  try
    a.LoadFromFile('C:\1.txt');
    b.LoadFromFile('C:\2.txt');

    b.Sorted := True;

    for i := a.Count - 1 downto 0 do
    begin
      // Check if line of file 'a' are present in file 'b'
      // and delete line if true

      if b.IndexOf(a[i]) > -1 then
        a.Delete(i);
    end;

    a.SaveToFile('C:\1.txt');
  finally
    b.Free;
    a.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Again, this is a slow and simple solution that loads whole files in RAM. It still will be much faster than using a ListBox. Sometimes simple is just enough for solving a one-time problem.

A faster method would be to create an index (eg. binary tree) of both files on hard disk and use this index to compare. That way you will not need to store the whole files on disk.

Comment: This is the same that I answered before ;)

Comment: You can save to lot of memory by only reading the file to be modified into a stringlist. The other file you can open and read line-by-line.

Comment: Look at `TStreamReader` and its `ReadLine()` method.

Comment: The similarities between these two answers are very striking indeed.

Comment: This answer is missing "var i:integer;". In this case I vote for the below solution which is the complete solution!