# Insert record in the middle of a binary file in Delphi

Tags: file, delphi, binary, pascal, records

I'm creating a program in Delphi and I need to insert a record in a binary file, but between 2 existing records. Can anyone help me ?

Comment: I wouldn't say duplicate, because you're talking about binary data, but same idea as this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13736707/modifying-or-deleting-a-line-from-a-text-file-the-low-level-way

Comment: What aspect of your task are you having difficulty with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to **insert**, then you'll have to create a new file with a different name, copy the old file content, up to the insert spot, to the new file, then write the new record to the new file and finally copy the rest of the old file to the new file. Then delete the old file and rename the new file to the name of the old one.

Original file:

```
[A][B][C][D][E][F][G][H]
            ^
            insertion point
```

First copy content before insertion point:

```
[A][B][C][D]
```

write new record:

```
[A][B][C][D][Z]
```

and then copy the rest:

```
[A][B][C][D][Z][E][F][G][H]
```

If you only want to replace a record, then take a look at random access I/O, either using old Pascal `Seek` and `BlockRead`/`BlockWrite`, or streams, using `TStream.Seek` and `TStream.Write`. The latter is the more contemporary way of doing things.

#### Update

As suggested in the comments, you can also do the following (using the same routines as described above):

Open the file for reading and writing, increase the size of the file by the size of the record to insert, move the content "above" the insertion point out of the way to the higher file "address" and then write the record to the insertion point.

Before:

```
[A][B][C][D][E][F][G][H]
            ^
            insertion point
```

then move E onward up:

```
[A][B][C][D][E][E][F][G][H]
            ^  <---------->
```

and finally write the new record:

```
[A][B][C][D][Z][E][F][G][H]
            ^  <---------->
```

If you want to copy content in chunks (say, 4k chunks), then don't forget to do it backward (from high file pointer to low), so you don't overwrite content you did not read yet. Or you use a double buffer. Or ...

---

You can make this as complicated as you wish. I personally would probably copy to a new file, delete the old and rename the new file and be done with it.

Comment: You don't need to create a new file. It would be best to increase the size of the file for the new inserted record size. Temporarily copy file contents after the insertion point into memory. Write new record into file and then write rest of the copied contents of the file from memory. This avoids the need to create a new file and copy whole contents of a file (in two steps) from one location to another. And in case if the file size is to great for data after insertion point to be stored in memory at once you can still do this in chunks.

Comment: I am always wary of copying entire files (especially if they are huge) into memory. Yes, you can increase the size, copy the content after the insertion point to a "higher" file location (in chunks or as a whole) and then "insert" the record. But I am not sure if that is more performant. I would do it my way. Note that if you do the copying in chunks, you must work backward to avoid overwriting content you did not read yet, or keep a double buffer.

Comment: Hmm what would be more quicker? Reading let us say 1 GB of data after insertion point and then writing it back after the  inserted record or copying 2 GB of data in two steps (one step for data before insertion point and another for data after the insertion point). My approach would only be slower if you would have to move the data in bunch of small chunks. As for your approach it also has one great disadvantage. What disadvantage? You need enough disk space to actually make a copy of existing file. So in case if original file is let us say 2 GB in size you would also need 2 GB of free space

Comment: @SilverWarior second method would be faster - but if someone went wrong in-between - you would have the damaged file. first method is slower but safe - it never destroys the old file before creating the correct new one, so if something went wrong - the user would at least have the old data, while with faster method he would have neither old nor new data, all gone.

Comment: And regarding to your edited answer. Don't and I really mean don't copy content in 4k chunks as this would hurt performance really bad. Instead you should at least use half of the hard disk cache sized chunks but best would be to make use of full had disk cache.

Comment: @Arioch'The Data corruption could happen in both cases. And because in first approach you are copying larger amount of data the chance for data corruption to occur is even greater. But yes in case if you are implementing system when you also want an old file version to be available for possible backup the second approach would be the best choice. But this is not the case for normal file changes. if it would be so then all computer programs would be using of such approach but only very few does.

Comment: @SilverWarrior: in my original case, the old file, which is only read, would very likely not be corrupted.

Comment: Then again, if the file is not sorted you may only copy E-cell to the very file tail,  getting (unless errors) ABCDZFGHE file, it may be good enough, or not, depending on the work domain

Comment: @SilverWarior it is funny.... You ask us how you manage file management and at the same time you lecture us how "normal programs" operate. Guess you take SysInternals ProcessMonitor and check how OpenOffice saves the files, how 7-zip and WinRar update archives, etc. But even if you are correct and majority of program insist upon destroying data before attempting to recreate it would not mean that lazy majority of programs do it safer than safer minority :)

Comment: 4KB is normal for HDD, but for flash media like SSD and MicroSD one better do with 256 kb chunks. Wikipedia: write amplification

Answer (score 0):

The approach is basically exactly the same as you would do for inserting an element into an array. Note it relies on records being the same size.

1. Read the *next* record from the file for later.
2. Overwrite the *next* record with the *new* record.
3. Move your "insert position" 1 record forward.
4. Repeat from 1, treating the record you read earlier as the one you want to insert.

Comment: I would not recommend using of such approach. Why? Because on hard drives this would result in terrible performance because you would be doing many small read and write operations. And while on SSD's the performance drop would not be so noticeable you would probably be increasing the wear of an SSD. Why? Because with a difference of a traditional hard drive where you can write each individual byte SSD requires that whole data cell is rewritten at once. So I must admit that Rudy's answer to be better.