# Deleting full lines from the begining of a logfile in Delphi

Tags: delphi, logging, file-io

I've developed a Delphi service that writes a log to a file. Each entry is written to a new line. Once this logfile reaches a specific size limit, I'd like to trim the first X lines from the beginning of the file to keep its size below the specified limit. I've found some code here on SO which demonstrates how to delete chunks of data from the BOF, but how do I go about deleting full randomly sized lines and not given chunks?

Comment: By simply reading X lines at a time, not fixed chunks. Depending on how you are accessing the file, you could use the system `Readln()` function or the `TStreamReader.ReadLine()` method, or you could load the file into a `TStringList` and then `Delete()` the first X strings from it. But no matter what, you need to read the file and then write the lines you want to keep to a new file. You can't delete data from the front/middle of a file in an inline manner

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modifying or deleting a line from a text file the low-level way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13736707/modifying-or-deleting-a-line-from-a-text-file-the-low-level-way)